# How can i transmit value with javascript effectively?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a servo which can be controlled by writing in a file called /dev/servoblaster. I can control the servos via a web-server. I have a HTML- and a PHP-file. The servo.php file writes everything that it gets transmitted from the index.html in the file /dev/servoblaster.

The value (which later gets written in /dev/servoblaster) is generated by this input element in the body tag:

```
<input type="range" id="tiltRange" value="140" max="170" min="60">
```

The value gets transmitted from this java-script function:

```
function tilt() { 
    var tilt = document.getElementById("tiltRange").value;
    document.getElementById("tilt_Range").innerHTML = tilt;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "servo.php?dir=P1-11=" + tilt, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

This function (same HTML-file)

```
setInterval(tilt, 50);
```

repeats the tilt() function and i can control the servo smoothly with the range-input.

**But it's obviously not the best solution. I want that *only when i change the position of the range-input* it should start sending the value and not the whole time.**

You can find the files here:

[index.html](http://pastebin.com/RXPmPvtf)
[servo.php](http://pastebin.com/XDS6FNrz)

Comment: Use the `input` event. [Here's an example of how to use it.](http://jsfiddle.net/girlie_mac/GKY2A/)

Comment: I found a good solution for the problem. I used a Event-listener.